# menu not visible in chrome but works in IE

Tags: google-chrome

I am having a coding issue with Chrome and Firefox. The page I'm building has a menu that is placed with an anchor and it shows fine in IE but not Chrome or FF. Here is the code for the anchor:

```
<TR>
<TD bgColor=#FFFFFF height=31 colSpan=4 noWrap><a name="awmAnchormenu"></a></TD>
</TR>
```

I was told this, but not sure how to make the change:

> This is because you used "name" instead of ID in the Positioning Element (the `<a>` link you used).
>
> First of all, due to formatting issues I strongly suggest using `<div>` or `<span>` instead of `<a>`.
>
> Second, you have to use ID. Only IE considers "name" to work like an ID, so now your menu does not show in any other browser.

Comment: Maybe the person you were told by could help you.

Comment: Wow, that is some seriously dated HTML.  Hardly a quoted parameter in sight.

Comment: @Surreal Dreams: my thoughts exactly ;)

Comment: *cries*. How do people keep doing this?!?!?! First off, *never* use tables for layout. Also, use CSS stylesheets instead of inline decelerations. And as it was previously mentioned, use quotes around parameters. It will save you hair.

Comment: Agree with most people above.  An additional thought.. If you are changing styles on 'hover' for the link, or anchor tag,(with css) you will not want to change.  I am pretty sure IE 6 does not support hover styles on anything except anchor tags(Basically what I am trying to say is, DOWN WITH IE 6!)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not fixing the HTML itself, but I will fix the problem according to the person who instructed you.  Try this:

```
<TR>
    <TD bgColor=#FFFFFF height=31 colSpan=4 noWrap><a name="awmAnchormenu" id="awmAnchormenu"></a></TD>
</TR>
```

**edit:**  OK, I can't take it.  Here's the HTML fixed.

```
<tr>
    <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" height="31" colspan="4" nowrap="nowrap">
        <a name="awmAnchormenu" id="awmAnchormenu"></a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

It's still pretty old-school, but at least it's following *some* rules.

Answer (score 0):

It's as he said. Replace `name` with `id`.  Also consider changing `a` to `div` or `span`.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
<tr>
     <td bgColor="#FFFFFF" height="31" colSpan="4" nowrap="nowrap">
          <span id="awmAnchormenu"></span>
     </td>
</tr>
```

also , you should not use capital letters for the html tags.

Answer (score 0):

It means you should change `<a name="awmAnchormenu"></a>` to `<span id="awmAnchormenu"></span>`.